# when only text_1 get number, how rotate the only red arrow with same button, when other edit text is empty?

Tags: android, image, rotation

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    redarrow = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.red);
    greenarrow = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.green);
    yelowarrow = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.yelow);

    text_1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text_1);
    text_2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text_2);
    text_3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text_3);

    button_rotate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_rotate);


    button_rotate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            float text1 = Float.parseFloat(text_1.getText().toString());
            float text2 = Float.parseFloat(text_2.getText().toString());
            float text3 = Float.parseFloat(text_3.getText().toString());

            red.setRotation(text1);
            green.setRotation(text2);
            yelow.setRotation(text3);
        }
    });
}
```

Screenshot:

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

```
  private ObjectAnimator rotatingObjectAnimator;

  rotatingObjectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(red, "rotation", 0f, 180f);
  rotatingObjectAnimator.setDuration(1000);
  rotatingObjectAnimator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
  rotatingObjectAnimator.start();
```

**Update:**

The above lines starts a rotation animation the arrow. It basically rotates the arrow by 180 degrees. When the animation ends, the arrow stays there. Hence solving the problem. You can put the above few lines in your on click listener.

Comment: Could you explain a bit what your code does and how it can be applied to solve the problem described in the question ?

Comment: I have three arrow images "red; green and yellow" I need to rotate red, green or yellow arrow one by one, when I edit digit in text _1, at the same time text _2 and text _3 were empty, it showed me the error, there is a images link

Comment: @GelaLataria Can you attach a stacktrace?